# Querying JSON with dynamic keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I need to convert the following JSON structure into a table using MySQL 8.0:

```
{
    "orders": {
        "923782782435": [{
            "SKU": "234OKOE",
            "total": 34.56
        }],
        "572547245745": [{
            "SKU": "252562",
            "total": 22.55
        }, {
            "SKU": "2273573",
            "total": 400.13
        }],
        "5245724525": [{
            "SKU": "234OKOE",
            "total": 34.56
        }, {
            "SKU": "2273573",
            "total": 400.13
        }]
    }
}
```

Expected SQL query output:

```
923782782435 234OKOE   34.56
572547245745 252562    22.55
572547245745 2273573   400.13
5245724525   234OKOE   34.56
5245724525   2273573   400.13
```

It seems that currently supported functionality doesn't allow fetching object keys, just values. I guess, I could use JSON_KEYS function and join it with result of JSON_TABLE but that solution seems to be sub-optimal.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're right, `JOIN`ing with `JSON_KEYS` is the only option at present.

Comment: I suggest the query would be way easier if you stored data in normal form, not in JSON.

Comment: I have to extract data from an audit system and generate report for revenue assurance purpose. This data is not meant to be queried in real time.